# Error after cast : lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c, type-conversion, lvalue

I have a function which encrypt a string with Vigenère cipher method.

```
void encrypt(const char * key, char * str) {
    [...]
    char * copy = duplicate(key); /*Like the strdup() function. It creates a copy of the string on the heap.*/
    [...] /* Here , i ensure that copy has the same size as str*/
    size_t k; 
    for (k=0;k<strlen(str);k++){
        if ((str[k]>='A' && str[k]<='Z') || (str[k]>='a' && str[k]<='z')){
            str[k]=(((str[k]+copy[k]))%26)+'A'; /*errors are at this line*/
        }
        else {
            str[k]=str[k];
        }
}
```

When i try to encrypt , i get this error

```
error: conversion to 'char' from 'int' may alter its value [-Werror=conversion]
```

I understand that str[k] may need to be cast into char type (or int?) but when i replace str[k] by (char)str[k] or (int)str[k],
i get a new error.

```
error : lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Here, i understand that (char)str[k] is not an lvalue but i don't understand why because str is a pointer on a char , not a const char.

So i really want to know why str|k] is considered as not-lvalue because i don't understand why at the moment.

Thanks.

Comment: You placed that cast before the statement?

Comment: No i just add (char) at line 7. like this : (char)str[k]=(((str[k]+copy[k]))%26)+'A';

Comment: The result of a cast is never an lvalue. Adding a cast on the left side of the assignment was wrong. Forget that and worry about the original problem.

Comment: I don't get that error unless I specify `-Werror=conversion`. Are you specifying that option? If so, why? Also, since the code in the question doesn't produce the error in the title, you might want to change the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(char) x` produces a new, temporary value of type `char` (regardless of the type of `x`). You cannot assign to such a value, just like you cannot assign something like `x + y = z`, or `1 + 2 = n`.

If you want to silence the conversion warning, you should cast the value that you are assigning:

```
str[k] = (char) ( /* ... */ );
```

Comment: The conversion is done implicitly by the assignment. Adding a cast should make no difference. As I said above, I get that error only if I specify `-Werror=conversion`, with or without the cast.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I don't understand -- the whole point of the answer is to silence the warning; which part are you objecting to?

Comment: The code in the question doesn't produce the warning unless that option is specified. When I tried it myself, adding the cast didn't make the warning go away. If like to know whether and why the OP is using that option.